# React image loading in first render

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

I have a strange behavior for rendering images in React. In the first render images are not rendering in frontend but when I change screen size to mobile and then again to desktop, I am able to see all my images in website. I have tried importing directly images or using webpack but behavior is still same. Any idea about this problem? Thanks in advance

```
import React from 'react'
import { useCssHandles } from 'vtex.css-handles'
import Tilt from 'react-parallax-tilt';
import { FormattedMessage } from 'react-intl'
import appliancesThumb from "./images/appliancesThumb.png"
import cleaning from "./images/cleaning.png"

interface Promotions { }

const Promotions: StorefrontFunctionComponent<Promotions> = ({ }) => {

  const CSS_HANDLES = ["promotionsMainDiv", "promotionImages", "promotionTitle", "promotionsWrapper", "promotionFigure"]
  const handles = useCssHandles(CSS_HANDLES)

  return <div className={`${handles.promotionsMainDiv}`}>

    <Tilt tiltMaxAngleX={16} tiltMaxAngleY={18} transitionSpeed={1500} tiltReverse>
        <div className={`${handles.promotionsWrapper}`}>
          <figure className={`${handles.promotionFigure}`}>
            <img className={`${handles.promotionImages}`} src={appliancesThumb} />
            <FormattedMessage id="store/countdown.firstPromotionImage">
            {message => <h3 className={`${handles.promotionTitle}`} >{message}</h3> }
            </FormattedMessage> 
          </figure>
        </div>
    </Tilt>
    

    <Tilt tiltMaxAngleX={16} tiltMaxAngleY={18} transitionSpeed={1500} tiltReverse>
        <div className={`${handles.promotionsWrapper}`}>
          <figure className={`${handles.promotionFigure}`}>
            <img className={`${handles.promotionImages}`} src={cleaning} />
            <FormattedMessage id="store/countdown.secondPromotionImage">
            {message => <h3 className={`${handles.promotionTitle}`} >{message}</h3> }
            </FormattedMessage> 
          </figure>
        </div>
    </Tilt>

    <Tilt tiltMaxAngleX={16} tiltMaxAngleY={18} transitionSpeed={1500} tiltReverse>
        <div className={`${handles.promotionsWrapper}`} onClick={()=>window.location.href =`promoties`}>
          <figure className={`${handles.promotionFigure}`}>
            <img className={`${handles.promotionImages}`} src={require('./images/placeholder.png')} />
            <FormattedMessage id="store/countdown.thirdPromotionImage">
            {message => <h3 className={`${handles.promotionTitle}`} >{message}</h3> }
            </FormattedMessage>
          </figure>
        </div>
    </Tilt>
    
  </div>
} 

export default Promotions
```